# How to run windows phone app from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am developing phone gap application for windows phone.I am using visual studio 2010 & windows phone sdk 7.0.
How to run my application on windows phone 8?Or I have to run it on windows phone 7.
I am unable to connect my windows phone os 8 to visual studio.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a windows phone 8 device which you want to use for app debugging purpose, you NEED the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 installed, which needs at least a 64-bit Windows 8 Pro or better.

Answer (score 0):

If i haven't forgotten something, then Phonegap has 2 project templates - 1 for WP7 and 1 for WP8. Which allows to think that WP7 project won't run on WP8.